# Postgresql script doesn't work as I expect

Tags: postgresql, syntax

```
DO $$
DECLARE companyNrs text[] = ARRAY(SELECT LPAD(companynr::text, 5, '0') FROM s_users);
        companyNr text;
BEGIN
  FOREACH companyNr IN ARRAY companyNrs
  LOOP        
    raise notice 'notice message %', companyNr;
  END LOOP;
END; $$
```

The postgresql script above works perfectly on DataGrip. But if I add a DECLARE statement into the loop(as below), it gives multiple syntax errors. What is the rule here ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you find such syntax in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html)?

You need declare variables in the same [block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html).

```
DO $$
DECLARE companyNrs text[] = ARRAY[1,2,3];
        companyNr text;
        v_sql text;
BEGIN
  FOREACH companyNr IN ARRAY companyNrs
  LOOP
    v_sql := format('foo bar %L', companyNr);
    raise notice 'notice message %', v_sql;
  END LOOP;
END; $$;
```

Or it is possible to declare another sub-block:

```
DO $$
DECLARE companyNrs text[] = ARRAY[1,2,3];
        companyNr text;
BEGIN
  FOREACH companyNr IN ARRAY companyNrs
  LOOP
    --
    -- Create a subblock
    --
    DECLARE
        v_sql text;
    BEGIN
        v_sql := format('foo bar %L', companyNr);
        raise notice 'notice message %', v_sql;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END; $$;
```

Subblocks with `EXCEPTION` clause are implicit savepoints and have a performance impact. Not sure about subblocks without `EXCEPTION` clause. They may not be cheap syntactic sugar either.